# C++ Make Your Own Class asValue for dictionary

Tags: c++-cli

I am using VS2010, c++ windows forms application.

Here is my class

```
 #pragma once
    public ref class FrameMatrix
    {
    public:
        FrameMatrix(void);
        FrameMatrix(int IdNm, int ClmnAmnt, int RwsAmnt);
        String^ FMName;
        int FMIdentificationNumber;
        array<array<double>^>^ FMArray;
    };
```

Now I try to put it into Dictionary as value.
And I get unresolved tokens.

```
#pragma once
#include "FrameMatrix.h"
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Dictionary<int, FrameMatrix^>^ ImportedData;
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
            ImportedData = gcnew Dictionary<int, FrameMatrix^>;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses:

```
ImportedData = gcnew Dictionary<int, FrameMatrix^>();
                                                  ^^
```

If that doesn't fix the error, please post the exact error message you're getting.